# How do I add this code to my Appcelerator/Titanium project?

Tags: flash, webview, titanium, appcelerator

What I want to do is print out every URL that is loaded within a WebView in my Appcelerator project. Let's call it a console window. I also want to log URLs requested by Flash plugins. Upon searching these forums, it appears that `onLoadResource` should work, but I'm not sure how to implement this Java code into my Appcelerator project.  I assume I'll need a custom module?  The code I think I need would be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
    // Somehow give my Titanium app access to the url...
}
```

Any pointers on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"onLoadResource" does look like what you want. And you are correct in assuming you will need to build a custom module (because onLoadResource is not exposed by Titanium Mobile).

Your quickest route forward would be to copy all of the existing Titanium Mobile web view related code in to a module you create, and then override the onLoadResource method, firing an event or logging the loaded URL.

Here's a link to the relevant folder in GitHub: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/widget/webview

Answer (score 0):

that looks like java code... Appcelerator using javascript. You might find better luck in the Appcelerator forum.

Here is some code I wrote to find links that might get you started

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/2847924695/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-disable-links-in-webview

Comment: Yeah, it's Java code, and as I stated in my post I think I need a custom module.  Custom Java modules can be implemented into Titanium.